# changing the class name of a div in jquery

Tags: ajax, jquery

When clicked the button I want to get change the name of the class of li under mycontent div. Is there a way to do that? my codes are below.

```
<div id="mycontent">
    <ul id="sortable">
    <li id="1" class="myclass">Item 1</li>
    <li id="2" class="myclass2">Item 2</li>
    <li id="3" class="myclass3">Item 3</li>
    <li id="4" class="myclass4">Item 4</li>
    </ul>
</div>

$(document).ready(function()
    {
  $("#submit_prog").click(
      function()            
          {                    
            $.ajax(
             {
              type: "POST",
              url: "sort2.php",                            

             });    
         });
     });
```

Comment: Is an Id starting with a number valid?

Comment: @gdoron , you are absolutely correct , can not use numbers for id

Comment: *"ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"), underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".")."*  Read [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/70579/what-are-valid-values-for-the-id-attribute-in-html)

Answer (score 3):

I'm pretty sure the jQuery would be something like:

```
$("#mycontent li.myclass2").removeClass("myclass2").addClass("myOtherClass2");
```

...etc for each `li` element.

if you wanted to change the class of *all* of `li` the elements, use this:

```
$("#mycontent li").removeClass("myclass myclass2 myclass3 myclass4").addClass("myOtherClass2");
```

you would add that to a click event on the button (in this example with id `myClassChangeButton`):

```
$("#myClassChangeButton").click(function(){
    $("#mycontent li.myclass").removeClass("myclass").addClass("myOtherClass");
    $("#mycontent li.myclass2").removeClass("myclass2").addClass("myOtherClass2");
    $("#mycontent li.myclass3").removeClass("myclass3").addClass("myOtherClass3");
    $("#mycontent li.myclass4").removeClass("myclass4").addClass("myOtherClass4");
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to use jquery codes above in sort2.php? Because I want to execute it in server side.

Comment: If I understand your question, as far as I know, there is no way to use jQuery code or even anything similar on the server side - it is a _browser_-based (DOM-manipulating) _JavaScript_ framework. There is no PHP implementation. -- on that note, if you're asking how to do this server side (where there's no DOM) I'm not sure why you wouldn't just use PHP scriptlets to set the class -- I might not understand your question, though.

Answer (score 1):

Use this to change the class `myclass2` from a `li` element in the div with the id `mycontent`:

```
$('#button').click(function(){
    $('#mycontent li.myclass2').removeClass().addClass('newClass');
});
```

**Edit:**

Code Jockey mentioned that this will remove all classes from the li element with .myclass2
That's right, so for future readers, **this will only remove .myclass2**:

```
$('#mycontent li.myclass2').removeClass('myclass2').addClass('newClass');
```

Comment: bear in mind this will remove all classes from the list items (if there are more than one class on each) which doesn't apply to the example, but might apply in the actual situation.

Comment: Thank you for mentioning this, I edited the answer for future readers! +1 for your answer.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Try this:

```
$('.button').click(function(){
     $('li#4') .removeClass();
     $('li#4').addClass('your_class')
});
```

Something along this lines should work